# What software should I use to design an audio circuit?

Tags: audio, simulation, cad

I'm looking for a simulator that will enable me to listen to the output, and ideally run on Linux and / or OSX. A front end for visually laying out components would be excellent too, but is not strictly necessary.

Comment: *A front end for visually laying out components would be excellent*. But if that is missing, what would your input then be???? Or do you mean designing a circuit board? Also, what are you willing to pay? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think something like that exists. You can [use wav files](http://electrostud.wikia.com/wiki/Using_WAVE_files_as_input/output_in_LTSpice) as input (for sources) in LTspice and save the output in that format too, but I have not tried myself that function. It's apparently very slow.

And if just want to do audio programming (no real electronic components), there are plenty of options: SuperCollider, [Max/MSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_(software)) etc. The latter (which also has a free equivalent as [Pure Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_Data)) actually uses blocks that implement DSP functions and which you connect as a circuit, but going from that to an actual implementation in electronics is a long way.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip on LTSpice. I'm exploring it now.